# Proving this is a partial order ($\subseteq$)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So the question is:
Prove for any set $S$, the relation $\subseteq$ is a partial order on $P(S)$, the power set of $S$.
I see no relevance of mentioning the power set of $S$, as the proof just uses simple set laws and algebra to show antisymmetry, transitivity and reflexivity. Am I missing something?
My solution:
Suppose $A \in P(S)$. Then $A \subseteq A$ by definition (this is true in general anyway).
Suppose $A,B \in P(S)$ such that $A\subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$. Then $A=B$ (by letting $x$ be an element in $A$, showing it belongs in $B$ and vice versa) (which would be true regardless of the power set anyway)
Suppose $A,B,C \in P(S)$ and $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq C$ then $A\subseteq C$ by doing the same method as above.

I'm not sure why they needed to mention the power set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct, and you are also correct that there was no use of the fact that you were within a power set. However, the question did need to mention some set on which to define the ordering $\subseteq$. The power set of some arbitrary set is a perfectly good choice.